# bundle update and install hang forever on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

My screen has been stuck here for over 10 minutes.

```
Fetching https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....................
```

I'm in US and internet speed is 100MB,

Ruby version ruby 2.4.3p205
Not sure what can i do to fix this deprecate web project.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use Puma as the app server

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
# gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'bundler'

group :development, :test do
    # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
    gem 'pry'
    gem 'pry-nav'
    gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
    gem 'pry-awesome_print'
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'rb-readline'
    gem 'zeus', '0.15.4'

    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'rspec-deep-ignore-order-matcher'
    gem "rspec-expectations"
end


group :development do
    # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
    gem 'web-console'
    gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    # gem 'spring'
    # gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
    gem 'puma'
    gem 'capistrano'
    gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
    # gem 'capistrano-puma',  require: false
    gem 'capistrano3-puma', github: "seuros/capistrano-puma"
    gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
    gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
    gem 'capistrano-sidekiq'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'
gem "hirb-unicode"
gem "awesome_print", require: "ap"
gem "koala", "~> 2.2"
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'unirest'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'oxford_dictionary'
gem 'uuid', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.8'
# gem 'mailgun_rails'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'redis-namespace'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '1.1.8'
gem 'rspec' # without the require: false
```

Comment: Try with the `--verbose` flag (`bundle update --verbose`).

Comment: don't work. just stuck at
Resolving dependencies................................................
Rails ecosystem is so broken..

Comment: what bundler version are you using?

Comment: version : 2.1.3 ....

Comment: I had a non-production rails app where the bundle update had run almost two days. From time to time it took hours when I upgraded an app. After having one that ran overnight but never finished I had enough. I decided to delete the Gemfile.lock file and run it again. It took a few minutes to run. Not the best solution in my opinion but it works. I will do this when I upgrade my rails apps from 6.1 to 7.